# change the height of a UICollectionReuseableView (collection section header) dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I am trying to set the height of the section headers for a `UICollectionView` dynamically, but using the code below, I am not seeing anything change. The view is drawn with the correct items in it but the height will not budge. Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I can't seem to find anything related specifically to the `UICollectionView` object. Thanks in advance.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoVideoHeaderCell *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                          withReuseIdentifier:@"videoHeaderView"
                                                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // photos
        [headerView setSection:@"Photo"];
    } else {
        [headerView.VehicleDetailView removeFromSuperview];
        CGRect frame = headerView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 60;
        [headerView setFrame:frame];
        [headerView setNeedsDisplay];
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [headerView setSection:@"Video"];
    }

    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your delegate should implement the following function, assuming you're using a flow layout:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You can return a different size for each header. In horizontally scrolling collection views, only the width is used. In vertically scrolling ones, only the height is used. The unused value is ignored — your view will always be stretched to fill the full height/width of horizontal/vertical collection views, respectively.

There is a corresponding method for footers, too.

Comment: this works,  but how do i tell which section i am editing,  i only want to do it for section at index 1

Comment: Use the `section` parameter in the method. Store which section you're editing in an ivar and then compare them. If they're not the same, return the layout's `headerReferenceSize`.

Comment: sorry for being a complete noob here but the headerReferenceSize is not part of the collectionViewLayout...  do i need to create an instance of the header to read the frame?

Comment: Nope - cast the `collectionViewLayout` — `return [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout headerReferenceSize];`.

Comment: Hero again @AshFurrow - that is exactly what I was after, perfect :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer in Swift 3 and 4:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 250)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, instead of using the noisy delegate method, I prefer using this: (only works if you have a unique header size)

```
    let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout // Assuming you use the default flow layout 
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 42, height: 42) //Set the header size
```

Works  also with the itemSize:

```
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 42, height: 42) //Set a custom item size
```

This works great for setting an item size relative to your screen width for exemple.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionReusableView *header = [siteMapCollection dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier: @"headerID" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    NSString *headerText = @"This is my header";
    UIFont *labFont = [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size: 20.0];
    CGSize textSize = [dummyText sizeWithFont: labFont];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, header.frame.size.height - (textSize.height + 12), header.frame.size.width, textSize.height + 8)];
    [headerLabel setFont: labFont];

    [header addSubview: headerLabel];

    return header;
}
```